# Is it possible to define the space above and below a `figure` and `table` environment (`\intextsep`) locally?

Tags: graphics, floats

Having established how to define vertical spaces above and below `captions` globally as well as locally, I wonder if there is a way to also define `\intextsep` locally. Also, having `floating` disabled by using the `H` parameter provided by package `float`, I assume that `\textfloatsep` is not an issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\setlength{\intextsep}{50.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=10pt]{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

Some text...

\begin{figure}[H]
\captionsetup{font=Large,skip=5pt}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
\caption{This is a figure.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

... more text...

\begin{figure}[H]
\captionsetup{font=tiny,skip=15pt}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
\caption{This is another figure.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

... still more text...
\newpage
Text...

\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{font=small,skip=10pt}
\centering
\caption{This is a table.}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 7 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

... end of text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not be using `center` here, it adds extra space above and below the image. Replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`. (also why the `H`'s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define it inside `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` commands See below and check the first distance that has been set to 20pt:

Edit: As @daleif commented in the question `\begin{centrer}` and `\end{center}`
add extra space thet is not needed and increases the real spaces. So, I replaced with `\centering` for providing a better code to future visitors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\setlength{\intextsep}{50.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=10pt]{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

Some text...

\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{20.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\begin{figure}[H]
\captionsetup{font={Large},skip=5pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
\caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}

... more text...
\endgroup

\begin{figure}[H]
\captionsetup{font={normalsize},skip=15pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
\caption{This is another figure.}
\end{figure}

... still more text...
\newpage
Text...

\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{font=small,skip=10pt}
\centering
\caption{This is a table.}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 7 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

... end of text.

\end{document}
```